# Make file inaccessible on cd/dvd

Tags: c#, pdf, unauthorized

I have a bit of a difficult use-case.

I have for example 20 pdf files on a CD along with a program, which is used to open these files. But I want the user, who is using the program, to be unable to open the pdf files from the filesystem. Only the program should be able to open these files (after the user has given the password to open the "archive")

I have no idea on how to start with this, hopefully somebody can give me a hint or a pointer.

Thank you guys in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Encrypt the files and have the program perform the decryption. Note that this won't necessarily make it impossible for the user to open the files without your program, but will make it inconvenient.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way to solve it as you have described it.
You can use the files system flag 'hidden', but many users have set their file explorer to see hidden files.
But of course you could scramble the file content (with a simple or complex encryption) or put it in a password protected zip.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an external tool that encrypts the file into an exe file.
e.g.

http://www.drmsoft.com/pdf-to-exe-encrypter.asp

You can run the exe and give password from your program.